# What is the displacement amplitude of a 140 db sound wave?

Tags: waves, acoustics, estimation, intensity

I am teaching a unit on sound in my upper elementary science class, and my students are curious about how far air molecules are actually being displaced in a sound wave. I told them that if the air molecules were actually oscillating a foot or more they would probably be killed by the pressure. I would like to get actual, accurate information about this. I'm not a sound expert. I do know that the 'threshold of pain' for sounds is around 140 dB, so I am assuming that would be a good place to start in terms of measuring the amplitude of a sound wave.
So how far the closest answer I've been able to find is that

> "A sound with an intensity of 1*10-12 W/m2 corresponds to a sound that will displace particles of air by a mere one-billionth of a centimeter. The human ear can detect such a sound."
> (https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/Lesson-2/Intensity-and-the-Decibel-Scale)

If I were to measure a sound wave's amplitude in meters, are they measured in nanometers? How high of amplitude would be dangerous to a human?

Comment: If you're measuring the sound wave amplitude in meters, you're measuring the displacement of the particles. This displacement is longitudinal to the direction of propagation of the wave, not transverse to it, so it's a bit confusing to call it a "height".

Comment: [This page](https://physics.info/intensity/) links together the concepts of particle displacement, sound pressure, and sound intensity in an easily followed (if sometimes hand-wavy) way.

Comment: Using those relations, one can calculate the predicted displacement for 140 dB at 1 kHz at sea level to be 80 µm. I can't comment as to whether this is realistic.

Comment: @Chemomechanics, That implies a displacement of about 8 pm at 0 dB, which is normally considered the threshold of human hearing, so this number is really close to the 10 pm value given in OP's post. 
But, OP, the displacement for a given intensity will depend on the frequency and the acoustic impedance of the medium, so don't take it as a universal truth.

Answer (score 7):

There are two equations you need. Firstly the sound intensity in decibels (the *SPL*) is related to the RMS sound pressure by:

$$ SPL = 20 \log_{10}\left(\frac{\Delta P_{rms}}{2 \times 10^{-5}} \right) $$

We are going to need the pressure so we'll rearrange this to:

$$ \Delta P_{rms} = 2 \times 10^{-5} \times 10^{SPL/20} \tag{1} $$

Now the second equation. This relates the pressure $\Delta P_m$ to the displacement $\Delta s_m$ by:

$$ \Delta P = v\rho\omega \Delta s \tag{2} $$

So we can combine equations (1) and (2) to give the rather unwieldly equation:

$$ 2 \times 10^{-5} \times 10^{SPL/20} = v\rho\omega \Delta s $$

And rearranging gives us the equation we need for the maximum displacement of the air molecules in a sound wave.

$$ s = \frac{2 \times 10^{-5} \times 10^{SPL/20}}{v\rho\omega} \tag{3} $$

In this equation $v$ is the speed of sound ($343$ m/s), $\rho$ is the density of the air ($1.2$ kg/m³) and $\omega$ is the angular frequency i.e. $2\pi$ times the frequency in hertz. And since we used the RMS pressure equation (3) will give us the RMS displacement.

So for example if we take the SPL to be $140$ dB and the frequency to be $1$ kHz we get the displacement to be 78 microns.

I wish I had a reference for all this, but I found the equations in some old notes with the comment "this is proved in the textbook". Sadly I didn't write down which textbook.

Comment: Thank you! Also, @The Photon, I thought about not calling it 'height' but I wasn't sure what would be more accurate. 'Distance' sounds vague and 'length' would (to me) be more directly related to wavelength, which is (from what I understand) related to a totally different measurement for sound waves. What label would you use?

Comment: @SaraiLeia, you can talk about the *displacement* of the particles.